# How to unsubscribe an event from inside the event handler?

Tags: f#

My code subscribes to an event and it needs to unsubscribe (`Dispose`) once the event has been handled. However this looks like a chicken-egg problem. Using `rec` doesn't work and I cannot find how to do it.

It there any well-konwn pattern to bypass this limitation?

```ml
let process = new Process()
let exitSubscription = process.Exited.Subscribe (
    fun evntArg ->
        exitSubscription.Dispose()     <---------- Compiler complains here
        // do more something here.
     )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(you're saying in your question that `rec` doesn't work, but do not clarify why or how; so I'm going to ignore that part for this answer)*

**One way** to do this is to declare the value "recursive" with the `rec` keyword. This will allow the value initialization code to reference the value itself - just like with a recursive function.

```
let rec exitSubscription : IDisposable = process.Exited.Subscribe (
    fun evntArg ->
        exitSubscription.Dispose()
        // do more something here.
     )
```

This will work, but will also produce a warning saying "*this is a recursive value, and I can't tell if you're actually accessing it while it's being constructed, so you have to make sure that you don't, and if you do anyway, it'll be a runtime error*".

Note that you also have to add a type signature to the variable, otherwise the compiler can't quite grok it and complains that it might not have a `Dispose` method.

**Another way** is to make the variable mutable and then mutate it:

```
let mutable exitSubscription : IDisposable = null
exitSubscription <- process.Exited.Subscribe (
    fun evntArg ->
        exitSubscription.Dispose()
        // do more something here.
     )
```

Here you have to use a type signature too (for the same reason), and you have to initialize it with `null`, because there is no such thing as an uninitialized variable.

Also, this is a tiny bit less safe, because the variable is mutable, and that's always a source of bugs. As long as you pinky-promise not to mutate it (beyond this initialization), you're ok.

**But a "proper" way** is to use an observable combinator to limit the observable to only one element. That way you don't have to unsubscribe explicitly, which is always more reliable:

```
#r "nuget: System.Reactive"

open System.Reactive.Linq

process.Exited.Take(1).Subscribe (
    fun evntArg ->
        // do more something here.
     )
```

Comment: Worked perfect. I was confused, `rec` was then correct and the error that I saw was because i didn't annotate the type IDisposable. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, the answer was unfinished, I just added the final part. Please check it out.

Comment: Ah I see. `Take(1)` does the trick. Yes, it looks better. Thank you again.